# Run simple Shell command on SwiftUI project

Tags: swift, macos, shell, swiftui, terminal

I'm just looking for run a simple command (eg. "open -a Notes") using Process in a SwiftUI project and I'm having an issue running the command. I guess my path is off but I'm not 100% sure what it should be.

What's below is in the action of a button and I've disabled the sandbox option too.

Any help is appreciated!

```
 let process = Process()
                process.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
                process.arguments = ["open -a Notes"]
                process.launch()
                process.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: You don't need shell for that and even don't need to turn off sandbox. Look at NSWorkspace.openApplicationAtURL...

Comment: Also, there won't be anything SwiftUI-specific about this -- just Swift.

Comment: @Asperi I'm just trying to run something simple right now before I run a local translation job on a project

Comment: @jnpdx It was just for context and "Swift" is being used as one of the tags